# Specify odbc driver manager on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, odbc, unixodbc

I am attempting to install an odbc driver on my CentOS 7 server. I'm following the instructions for installing the driver [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/ODBC/SimbaAthenaODBC_1.0.5/Simba+Athena+ODBC+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf)(pdf).

After downloading the rpm file with wget and running with yum localinstall I see a summary in the shell and it looks like the driver installed.

```
yum list | grep SimbaAthenaODBC
SimbaAthenaODBC-64bit.x86_64           1.0.5-1                       installed
```

Where I'm getting confused is in specifying the odbc driver manager for my machine.

From the documentation:

> You need to make sure that your machine uses the correct ODBC driver manager to load the driver. To do this, set the library path environment variable

After I installed above the instructions say

> "The Simba Athena ODBC Driver files are installed in the /opt/simba/athenaodbc directory."

Sure enough:

```
ls -l /opt/simba/athenaodbc/
total 1616
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      19 Jun 25 23:34 ErrorMessages
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   27970 Feb 26 07:33 EULA.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      16 Jun 25 23:34 lib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    9162 Feb 26 07:33 release-notes.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      42 Jun 25 23:34 Setup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1612290 Feb 26 07:33 Simba Athena ODBC Install and Configuration Guide.pdf
```

Then one more snippet from the documentation:

> If you are using a Linux machine, then set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the paths to the ODBC driver manager libraries. For example, if the libraries are installed in /usr/local/lib, then run the following command to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the current user session:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

When I visit this example path `/usr/local/lib` it's currently an empty directory.

Do I want to set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /opt/simba/athenaodbc/?

I'm confused because the documentation tells me the driver files are stored in `/opt/simba/athenaodbc/` however the example of setting a environment variable uses `/usr/local/lib`.

How should I specify which driver manager my machine should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` must include both the directory holding the ODBC driver *and* the ODBC driver manager.

So, you must locate the ODBC Driver Manager on your Linux machine, typically either [iODBC](http://iodbc.org) or [UnixODBC](http://unixodbc.org). You should be able to find these libraries with a command like

```
find / -name 'lib*odbc*.so*' -print
```

You'll need to add *that* directory as well as `/opt/simba/athenaodbc` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, with a command like --

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/simba/athenaodbc:/path/to/dir/containing/lib*odbc*.so*
```

Note 1 -- `/path/to/dir/containing/lib*odbc*.so*` is a placeholder in the command above. You must change this to the correct local directory, probably something like `/usr/lib` or `/lib`.

*Note 2 -- this is *adding* the two new directories to any existing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` value, not setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to only those two directories.*